# How to initiate a stored procedure in function

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, vb.net, stored-procedures

This code updates the fiscal year automatically...

```
 Dim yearVal As Double
 If Date.Now.Month = 10 OrElse Date.Now.Month = 11 OrElse Date.Now.Month = 12 Then
     yearVal = Date.Now.Year
 Else
     yearVal = Date.Now.Year - 1
 End If
```

Each year when this changes to the next year, I want to execute this sql stored procedure automatically...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.NewBudget
    @year int,
    @int nvarchar(3)

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT [NAOLI].[dbo].[BudgetReal]
    ([F_Year],[O_OrgCode],[O_OrgDesc],[S_SubObject],[S_SubDescrip],[B_BudgetAmt],[B_Initials],[B_CIPrefNo],[B_OrgBudgetAmt]) 
    SELECT @year as [F_Year],[O_OrgCode],[O_OrgDesc],[S_SubObject],[S_SubDescrip], 0.00 as [B_BudgetAmt],@int as [B_Initials],[B_CIPrefNo],[B_OrgBudgetAmt]
    FROM [NAOLI].[dbo].[BudgetReal]
END
```

GO

How can I make this happen?

This did the trick

```
Dim yearVal As Double
    If Date.Now.Month = 10 OrElse Date.Now.Month = 11 OrElse Date.Now.Month = 12 Then
        yearVal = Date.Now.Year
            If yearVal = Date.Now.Month = 10 OrElse Date.Now.Month = 11 OrElse Date.Now.Month = 12 Then
                dt = dal.ExecuteSelectStoredProc(dal.dbType.SqlServer, "NewBudget", "@year", DropDownList1.Text, "@int", )
            End If
    Else
        yearVal = Date.Now.Year - 1
    End If
```

Thanks for eveyone's help.

Comment: Are you sure that this stored procedure is syntactically correct? SELECT @year as [F_year] ???

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ADO.NET` to connect to your database.  You will need a Connection String based upon your RDBMS.  Then you could put this in a class and call it in your conditional`IF` statement block.

```
Dim sqlConnection1 As New SqlConnection("Your Connection String")
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim reader As SqlDataReader

cmd.CommandText = "dbo.NewBudget"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Parameters.Add("@year").Value = yearVal
cmd.Parameters.Add("@int").Value = intValue 'No idea why you have a Stored Procedure paramter called @int

cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1

sqlConnection1.Open()

reader = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
' Data is accessible through the DataReader object here.

sqlConnection1.Close()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7125bke(v=vs.80).aspx#Y1200

http://www.connectionstrings.com

Comment: In this case, since the proc is an update, he probably wants `ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Comment: I don't have a stored procedure called @int, that is one of the parameters and my sql server connection is housed through a seperate class in code behind not through that method.

Comment: @developthestars - I didn't say you had a stored procedure, I said stored procedure paramter.  If you already have a sql server connection in another class why did you not state this in your post or post the code?

Comment: Bc the connection to the database is not the question, I have the stored procedure I just needed to know how to include it with the above if statement to me it run at the correct time. I have since solved the problem, but thanks for the help.

Comment: And you did say stored procedure "I don't have a stored procedure called @int, that is one..." :)

Comment: @developthestars I said stored procedure parameter, check the comment in the code.  From your question I know your stored procedure name is dbo.NewBudget